# Unicode question in Python with Django

Tags: django, unicode

I have a function `client_groups` in a model that returns a list of "Group" objects:

```
return self.userprofile.client.get_groups()
```

Ex. of a returned list:

```
[<Group: Finance>, <Group: Recepção>,...]
```

If I just print these normally in a shell, as in, `print groups[1]`, it shows the right thing, which is `"Recepção"`.
This function gets used in my admin.py, in my `list_display` tuple.
How can I go about displaying

```
Finance, Recepção,...
```

in my Django's admin interface? 
I tried decoding it but I get an UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters.

In my admin.py:
list_display = ("username","email","first_name","last_name","number","client","client_groups","date_created",)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
u', '.join(group.someattr for group in self.userprofile.client.get_groups())
```

Comment: I ran your line and it worked. Just for curiosity, I ran my original code in the shell and compared my output with the new output. There is no difference as far I can tell. Could you explain why your code works, other than the fact that you joined the group items with a 'unicoded' comma-space ?